# CakePHP There is anyway to insert script inside <head></head> from view?

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

There is anyway to insert the $this->Html->script() inside the head tag?

If I do this with $this->Html->css(), I can do something like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->css('css', array('inline' => false));
?>
```

Comment: The same applies to scripts - as documented.

Comment: When I try the code simply vanish.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

If you set the **'inline'** parameter to **false**, the cake will try to print inside a Block.

If you for some reason delete this form your layout:

```
<head>
    <?php
        echo $this->fetch('script');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('meta');
    ?>
</head>
```

The script, the css and the meta won't be fetch, and the code will simply vanish when the 'inline' parameter is set to 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the code

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->css('css', array('inline' => false));
?>
```

inside your template. Take a look at app/View/Layouts/default.ctp. There you will see a template file (the default one, actually) with a complete html structure, a  and css pages being called the way you want to.

For more details: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't the case. I figured out the answer, but I can't post... I've deleted the $this->fetch('script') from the head tag from the layout. When this line don't exist, cakephp won't fetch the script/css with inline set to false.